# Correct way to create an EAR file for existing maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, weblogic, ear

I have an existing maven project that I am trying to make an `.ear` file out of. I have gone ahead and made a `WAR` module and a `JAR` module with my web project as the parent project. After this, I made another module names the `EAR` module and added the `WAR` and the `JAR` files to it as dependencies. Now I go on `Run as-> Maven install` in `Eclipse` and the process runs successfully. Now, I do see an EAR file made in the path `/EARModule/target/CAD.ear` which is stored in my eclipse workspace. I could copy paste and further use the `EAR` file for my purposes but is this the right way to obtain the `EAR` file? I need an `EAR` file for the existing project I had, so that I can deploy the same on `oracle weblogic server`. The `pom.xml` that was auto-generated for the `WAR` and the `JAR` modules are as follows - 
`WAR Module`-

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>CAD</groupId>
    <artifactId>CAD</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<groupId>CADWARModule</groupId>
<artifactId>CADWARModule</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>CADWARModule Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>CADWARModule</finalName>
</build>
</project>
```

`JAR Module`-

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>CAD</groupId>
    <artifactId>CAD</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<groupId>CADJARModule</groupId>
<artifactId>CADJARModule</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>CADJARModule</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Help much appreciated!

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the correct way to create an EAR file. The next step you are looking for is presumably to deploy it. To do that you will need to remove the deploy plugin from your WAR and JAR pom.xml files (if you are already deploying those) and add it into the pom.xml for your EAR file.

I'm not familiar with the weblogic maven plugin, but [here is the documentation page](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/maven.htm#WLPRG585) for it. That should give you all the information you need.

Comment: I have added the `pom.xml`'s for both the generated modules. Could you please take a look and tell me if there are any changes to be made? I dont see default deployment configs that came along with the file.

Comment: They both look fine. The one comment I have would be to move the properties to the parent pom.xml. That way you can access the same properties from all of the poms that inherit the parent. All you should need to do now is add in the configuration for the deployment plugin in your EAR pom.xml, then run mvn install deploy

Comment: thanks, but what if I wish to deploy the same using the oracle administration console? on `http://localhost:7001/console`? Any idea how I would go about that then? @ewanc

Comment: Well I don't know weblogic I'm afraid, but going by the servers I have used there should be a deployments section somewhere in the admin console. Just navigate to that and it should allow you to select a file to deploy. It would be much simpler to deploy using maven though, one command will build and deploy everything rather than requiring some manual actions on your part.

Comment: Okay, I havent really been familiar with how to deploy the same but I have asked anyways. Could you please take a look ? Thanks! :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086464/how-to-correctly-deploy-a-ear-file-on-oracle-weblogic-administrator-console @ewanc